# Getting date time always null back to controller in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

Using MVC3 and jQuery plugin datepicker.

I can see calender and I am able to set the date to the field. But when I post model back to controller, I am always getting null value for the property. And it is displaying that particular date as a not valid date.

This is my model.

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayName("PostTime")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? PostTime { get; set; }
```

And part of my view

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
    <legend>BlogPost</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostTitle)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostTitle)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostTitle)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostTime)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    <span class="datepicker">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostTime)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostTime)
    </span>
    </div>


    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#PostTime").datepicker({
                    showOn: 'both',
                    buttonImage: "/content/img/calendar_icon.png"
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BlogPost blogpost)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var db = new BlogPostContext();
        db.Add(blogpost);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(blogpost);
}
```

Can somebody what I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Using your code, I was unable to get the model to return a null value. Can you add your Controller action to the question so I can see what that code is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as getting an error saying it isn't a valid date, you'll need to specify the format of the datepicker:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#PostTime").datepicker({
                showOn: 'both',
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                buttonImage: "/content/img/calendar_icon.png"
            });
        });
```

Comment: tried that too. But it's not working. With the above format I am getting '11/November/20122012' as value.

Comment: it's working now. But I really don't understand the logic behind the validation failure. I thought it must be setting and validating the date in a same format.

Comment: Your data annotation which states the format has no knowledge of the jquery datepicker plugin.  You have to specify that format also, and it isn't failing validation because your property is a nullable DateTime.  If the format fails, the property is just set to null and this is considered valid.