# Always getting null in datetime field in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, jquery-ui-datepicker

my problrm is very similar to the question in **[Getting date time always null back to controller in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390622/getting-date-time-always-null-back-to-controller-in-mvc3)**

But, even though I have specified the DataAnnotations, and also specified the format in the datepicker, when I submit the form to the controller, I always get the value as ***"null"*** only in my dates column and it is not at all getting saved to the DB. Is there something else I am unware of?..
Is the jquery-1.8.2.js file a must as given in that post?...
 Can someone help me please?...

I also attached a **debugger to the chrome, and checked the network tab**. **Dates are being passed from UI** on the click of Submit, but I have no idea where it gets lost before it can reach the controller?...

**UPDATE:**

This is in my model:

```
        [Display(Name = "Checkout Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? CheckoutDate { get; set; }
```

This is my datepicker:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#CheckoutDate").datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    }); 
  });
 </script>
```

and my controller is a Submit action, taking the model as the parameter and returning a JsonResult...

Comment: Try calling your controller action directly from the web browser by specifying the date in MM-DD-YYYY format and let me know if this works.

Comment: WOW, there you are! It works perfectly when i pass the date like that. But I want the date to be passed in Indian format only... then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As far I have tried your code and I am getting datetime in Indian Format Correctly in Controller Side . I have implement in views following way...

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
{ 
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckoutDate)
</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" />
</div>
}
```

Try as per above I hope you will get datetime in correct way at controller side

At controller Side I hope you have as below

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(test model)
    {
        DateTime ? dtTime = model.CheckoutDate;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Is it working for you?.. REALLY?... But sorry @Dilip, it is still the same for me. I am afraid, No luck for me....;(

Comment: @user2771399 Ya its really working for me . Here I have added also Controller side in that "test" is model name . Now It may be useful to you .

Comment: oh.!!! it works now.....!! but, I dont understand why should I add a stmt like this in my controller, when I have specified the format in both model and datepicker?>

Comment: @user2771399 Very glad to know that now its working .  Are you talking about which statements ?

Comment: DateTime ? dtTime = model.CheckoutDate;

Comment: "model.CheckoutDate" is for getting post data from the instance of Model while we are using "DateTime ?" as property so need to store data into same object.

Comment: why was this stmt not needed when i passed the date in mm-dd-yyyy format?